# El Capitan update: This partition map modification would make a Windows partition unbootable

Tags: upgrade, macos

When trying to update to El Capitan (from Yosemite), I get the following error, and cannot proceed with the installation.

> This partition map modification would make a Windows partition unbootable

I have Windows installed with Bootcamp. Here is the disk:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            180.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:         Microsoft Reserved                         134.2 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                70.2 GB    disk0s4
   5: DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC               471.9 MB   disk0s5
```

There are no CoreStorage logical volume groups.

Is there anything I can do other than wipe the whole thing? What might cause this?

Comment: Do the random numbers and letters happen to be DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes they do, so that would mean it's some kind of a Windows recovery thing? Didn't realize what that was, got caught by the habit of anonymizing every hash etc.

Comment: When the `diskutil` does not recognize a partition type, it will present the GUID. A table describing GPT types is given [at this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Windows Recovery Environment it is, then. Anyway, any suggestions on how to solve the problem?